# Dapr: Failed to proxy request: proxy not initialized. daprd startup may be incomplete

Tags: dapr

I,m performing some tests with Dapr and Service Invocation using gRPC and have run in to an issue. I'm runnig Dapr in standalone mode and starts two applications like this:

```
dapr run --app-id App1 --app-port 10078 --dapr-grpc-port 11078 .\App1.exe
dapr run --app-id App2 --app-port 10114 --dapr-grpc-port 11114 .\App2.exe
```

When App2 tries to make a gRPC call to localhost:11114 to reach App1 i get an error

```
'Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="failed to proxy request: proxy not initialized. daprd startup may be incomplete.", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1650461046.340000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:10.16.100.25:11114","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":904,"grpc_message":"failed to proxy request: proxy not initialized. daprd startup may be incomplete.","grpc_status":2}")
```

App1 hosts a gRPC service on port 10078 and App2 host a gRPC service on port 10114. Both applications show up in the dashboard and the ports look correct.

When the app starts the log says *"API gRPC server is running on port 11114"* for App2 which seams correct. How can i diagnose this further?